# Hibernate datasource connection with JNDI

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jndi

I can get connection using JDBC

```
OracleDataSource ds  = (OracleDataSource) Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource").newInstance();
//...
Connection connection = ds.getConnection("USER", "PASSWORD");
```

But I can't do it for Hibernate using hibernate.connection.datasource and jni:
I tried different variants, but it does not work.

```
    String var1 = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource";
    String var2 = "java:/oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource";
    String var3 = "java:/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource";
    String var4 = "java:/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource";
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource",var1);
```

All variants throw exceptions when it tries to build SessionFactory:

```
 private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(Configuration configuration) {
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

Exceptions like this:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource]
```

maven dependecies for it:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>local.ora9iDriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>ora9iDriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/Users/micah/.m2/repository/local/ora9iDriver/oraDriver/1.0/ora9i.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you specify your datasource? If yes, where did you do it?

Comment: I think I did it at maven dependecies. I think I did it, because I could get connection using JDBC.

Comment: I could get class of DataSource for name and create instance of it.

Comment: When you work with JNI, you need to have the vars created somewhere. So far, what's you've done it tell maven that you will use the dependencies for Oracle JDBC connection. The fact you are having it working with the `Class.forName(...)` means dependencies are good. Now, you need to register your JNI name somewhere on an application server to be able to retrieve it. The other solution would be to create an external properties file to have the database server's URL and use it with the `Class.forName(...)`

Comment: DamCx, can you help me with example of registration JNI name and have its string reference for hibernate.connection.datasource setting?

Comment: First, what kind of app are you running? Is it a web app running on a web application server? If it isn't, you won't be able to register your datasource as a JNI reference.

Comment: It is just my playground project. I can use anything. I'm trying to integrate our old db with hibernate. But if we talk about the project as a whole, it is an enterprise application, which use some old ejb technology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174259/discussion-between-damcx-and-micah).

Answer (score 1):

Can you check out the [UCP with Hibernate blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/use-ucp-with-hibernate) and get some pointers?